# TSQL. Copy data from three tables into two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to copy data from three tables into two tables. I guess its easy task, but i cant figure it out. Plz help if you can.
Topic: Car brands and models.
My empty tables structure is:

```
CarBrands(Id, Title)
CarModels(Id, Title, CarBrandId)
```

Source tables structure is:

```
CarBrands(Id,Title)
CarModels(Id,Title)
LinkTable(Id, CarBrandId, CarModelId)
```

I need to copy data into my tables, but i cant figure out how to match CarBrandId column.

Comment: Basically you need to populate CarModels from CarModels/LinkTables (CarBrands remains). This should be a join by LinkTable.CarModelId=CarModels.Id ; give it a go and let us know if you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user Jayve! Finally i did it! 
In this situation i copy data from MySQL db to MSSQL db. Here is the code.
Copy CarBrands:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyDb.dbo.CarBrands ON
insert into MyDb.dbo.CarBrands(Id, Title, IsTruck)
select id_auto, name_auto, '0' from openquery(linked_mysql,'select * from auto')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyDb.dbo.CarBrands OFF
```

Copy CarModels:

```
--SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyDb.dbo.CarModels ON
insert into MyDb.dbo.CarModels(CarBrandId, Title)
select id_auto, name_model from openquery(linked_mysql, 'select s.id_model, s.id_auto, f.name_model from model f, com s where s.id_model = f.id_model')
--SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyDb.dbo.CarModels OFF
```